# The output from paramiko stdout incorrectly transfers lines

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, cmd, paramiko

I am trying to get a list of files with a specific extension on a remote computer(ssh, paramiko). However, when reading, not all the paths to the files are correctly displayed.

code:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=secret, port=port)
cmd = '''dir /s /b /n D:\\*.bat\n'''
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd, get_pty=True)
for line in stdout:
  print(line)
```

I get something like D: \ dir \ tes

t.bat

(Instead D: \ dir \ test.bat)

(part of the path is transferred to the next line) tried to read through read (). decode (), through readlines (), the result is the same, can you somehow solve the problem?

Comment: Why do you append a line-break to the `cmd` value?

Comment: just tried it. without line-break the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `get_pty=True`.

PTY should be requested only when you are implementing an interactive session. It brings side effects like the one you are experiencing.